# Issue with Crystal Reports upgrading existing app from Windows Server 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 with SAP Crystal Reports 2013 Viewer

Tags: asp.net, dll, crystal-reports, gac

I'm updating an ASP.NET web site from Server 2008 R2 to 2012 R2.  Our IT department seems to have misplaced our old copy of CR 11 so we've installed the CR 2013 Report Viewer as that is all our site uses to display reports online.  The DLLs in the GAC are all versioned 13.0.15.1840.  My main report page has the following assembly reference:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.15.1840, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

When I try to run a report from the page I'm getting the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.15.1840, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The DLL is clearly in the GAC and I've triple-checked the assembly version.  This seems like it should be pretty straightforward; anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

The important is:

> Make sure the location of your crystal report `directory`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm afraid I don't follow.